# Synchning Postgres & Elastic Search with Kafka Connect ( Debezium )

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have set up using docker a postgres image, aswell as a elastic search one.

What i'm trying to achieve is that i have a Vehicle entity ( on a microservice with spring data jpa) , as well as Vehicle document ( on a microservice with spring data elastic search ) .

```
@Document(indexName = "vehicles")
@Builder
@Data
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Field(name = "vin")
    private String vin;

    @Field(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Field(name = "model")
    private String model;

}
```

I also have jsons for kafka connect for elastic search and postgres:

```
{
  "name": "eh-vehicles-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class":
        "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
     "topics": "vehicles",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
                                    
    "key.ignore": "true",                                                        
    "type.name": "vehicles",
    "index.mapping.dynamic": false,
    
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  }
}


{
  "name": "postgres-vehicles-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",

    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "postgres",
    "schema.include.list": "public",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "database.server.name": "Vehicles",
    "database.server.id": "5401",

    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "public.history",

    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",

    "transforms":"Reroute",
    "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex":"(.*)vehicles",
    "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "vehicles",
    "transforms.Reroute.key.field.name": "id",
    "transforms.Reroute.key.enforce.uniqueness":"false"
  }
}
```

The problem is that after a entty is persisted in postgres, kafka will send it to elastic search, but it will store it in the following format:

```
"hits": [
{
"_index": "vehicles",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "vehicles+0+0",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"op": "c",
"before": null,
"after": {
"generation": "F10",
"cylindrical_capacity": 2000,
"country": "Germany",
"tva_deductible": false,
"km": "100000",
"fuel": "Diesel",
"first_owner": "John Doe",
"production_date": 15126,
"created_at": null,
"traction": "ALLWHEELS",
"owner_account_id": "4a2ac2a2-3323-4b42-8960-b044897a180c",
"first_registration_date": 15354,
"colour": "Black",
"soft_deleted": false,
"transmission": "AUTOMATIC",
"accident_free": true,
"vin": "WBAJB51090B513560",
"model": "5 Series",
"id": "739c9d56-d50b-4b17-a86a-e2561f54c1a9",
"power": 180,
"brand": "BMW",
"favorite_accounts": null
},
"source": {
"schema": "public",
"sequence": "[\"24015744\",\"24015744\"]",
"xmin": null,
"connector": "postgresql",
"lsn": 24015744,
"name": "Vehicles",
"txId": 506,
"version": "1.8.1.Final",
"ts_ms": 1676855693566,
"snapshot": "false",
"db": "postgres",
"table": "vehicles"
},
"ts_ms": 1676855694066,
"transaction": null
}
}
]
```

Which will be a problem when fetching it in the microservice for elastic search, because the payload is wrapped in another object and the wrong id will be fetched unless i do some aditional processing which i don't wanna do cause it seems a little bit boiler.

How can i configure kafka debezium in order to store in the vehicle index, only the entity, wihout aditional metadata like "after" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could flatten the after using debezium new record state extraction https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.1/transformations/event-flattening.html. With this only the after will be available and you could directly map to your Java object